# Git error al tratar de eliminar branch

Tags: git, github

Tengo una duda, regularmente creo una branch para nuevas cosas que se van a integrar más adelante, entonces cuando hago un PR ó un MR, como lo conozcan, intento borrar mi branch local ya una vez se hace el merge con la rama test, pero me aparece un error.

```
error: The branch mySuperBranch is not fully merged

If you are sure you want to delete it, run git branch -D mySuperBranch
```

Que pasa si forzó a borrar mi rama local, se borra el commit de mi rama test y pierdo esos cambios o que sucede:

Estos son los pasos que hago para llegar a ese punto

```
git add .

git commit -m"my example changes"

git push origin mySuperBranch

*PR/MR (Pull request on github/gitlab) Approved

git checkout test

git pull origin test

git branch -d mySuperBranch
```

**Error

```
error: The branch mySuperBranch is not fully merged

If you are sure you want to delete it, run git branch -D mySuperBranch
```

Esta bien si borro la branch local mySuperBranch con el -D

Comment: El error que te indica es que no está mergeada la rama. Dices que haces la PR, pero qué haces después? Haces el merge sobre "develop", y luego al borrar tu rama te da el error? O te da cuando todavía no has hecho el merge?

Comment: Hago el merge con el PR, ya una vez aprobado, bajo los cambios en develop/test y posteriormente quiero eliminar mySuperBranch y es ahí cuando me dice que no se puede eliminar porque no esta fusionada

Comment: Bueno me arriesgue a aplicar el comando al parecer en mi rama test si estan los cambios que se hicieron en el PR lo unico diferente es el commit id, quiza por eso dice que aún no esta fusionado en mySuperBranch, pero en realidad lo esta, y supongo me aparece ese mensaje de advertencia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás seguro de que quieres eliminar la rama `mySuperBranch`, ignorando el error que estás tenindo, entonces usa la opción `-D` en vez de `-d`.

```
$ git branch -D mySuperBranch
```

**-D**: Atajo para `--delete --force`.

**-d**, **--delete**: Borra una rama. La rama debe estar completamente fusionada en su rama *upstream*, o en `HEAD` si el *upstream* no se configuró con `--track` o `--set-upstream-to`.

**-f**, **--force**: Reinicia <nombre_rama> to <punto_de_inicio>, incluso si <nombre_rama> ya existe. Sin `-f`, **git branch** rechaza cambiar una rama existente. En combinación con `-d` (o `--delete`), permite borrar la rama sin tomar en consideración su estado de fusión, o incluso si apunta a un *commit* válido. En combinación con `-m` (o `--move`), permite renombrar la rama incluso si el nuevo nombre ya existe, lo mismo aplica para `-c` (or `--copy`).

Texto original en inglés:

> **-D**: Shortcut for `--delete --force`.
>
> **-d**, **--delete**: Delete a branch. The branch must be fully merged in its upstream branch, or in `HEAD` if no upstream was set with `--track` or `--set-upstream-to`.
>
> **-f**, **--force**: Reset  to , even if  exists already. Without `-f`, **git branch** refuses to change an existing branch. In combination with `-d` (or `--delete`), allow deleting the branch irrespective of its merged status, or whether it even points to a valid commit. In combination with `-m` (or `--move`), allow renaming the branch even if the new branch name already exists, the same applies for `-c` (or `--copy`).

Comment: Si funciono, note que no esta fusionada porque cambia el id del commit en el PR, pero igual como si se fusiono con mySuperBranch con Main en el PR, tengo la certeza de que mis cambios estan en Main y ya no necesito más de mySuperBranch, entonces si aplica usar git branch -D mySuperBranch, excelente gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya funcionado!